# How to split a string in the middle in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup to scrape some text from a website. I'm storing the scrape in a variable which is a string containing special characters, letters and numbers with no spaces.

For example: !012WR55wr"!.

What I would like to do is to split this string so that I can extract and convert the 55 into an integer and then use it to calculate things.

I tried to find a solution, but I only found two ways to split a string in python. The first is to split between the spaces in the string, which my does not contain. The second was to insert # in the string where I would like to split it. Because I am scraping the text, I am unable to place any # in the variable that contains the scrape.

Is there a way for me to extract the number 55 from the variable and set its type to an int?

Thank you!

EDIT:

Thank you everyone for the help. The problem is now solved and here is the solution:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "url"

url_response = requests.get(url)
url_content = BeautifulSoup(url_response.content, 'html5lib')

code = url_content.find('div', 'article_details').get_text()

print(code)
```

In my case this returns the following string: """ !At52R18wr"! """
Now in order to extract the number that I need I used what @Muluk provided:

```
extracted_integers =  re.findall(r"\d+" , code) 
extracted_integers = [int(i) for i in extracted_integers]
```

This returns two integers in a list, 52 and 18. In this case I'm interested in number 52 so I delete 18.

```
del extracted_integers[-1]
```

and finally I wanted to store the integer in a separate variable so that I can perform calculations on it.

```
for i in extracted_integers:
    value = i
value = int(value)

print(value)
```

Output: 52

Thanks again for the help! First time using stackoverflow!

Comment: ```re``` - https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp

Comment: What do you mean by "Because I am scraping the text, I am unable to place any # in the variable that contains the scrape"? Try posting your code so we can see what you are trying to do.

Comment: Is it based on a specific position or is it the 2nd series of numbers in the string you seek?

Comment: @JackFleeting This is the example of splitting that I found:                                                         
 txt = "hello, my name is Peter, I am 26 years old"

x = txt.split(", ")

print(x), in this example ',' is inserted where the text should be split. In my case I don't know what the content of the variable is, it is always random and the numbers that I would like to get are always different

Comment: @JimmySmith I'm scraping multiple websites, on one website the number might be at the beginning of the string, on another it might be at the end. Once I scrape the text from a website and print it on the terminal, I can look at it and say which of the two numbers is the one I need, then I would like to extract it and store it in a new variable. Once I know where the number is on a website, the position of the number will always be the same.

Comment: Can you post 3-4 examples with the target variables and desired outputs?

Comment: @SPersonDPerson the regex below would be the place to start.  If that isn't helping, could you add a snippet of the code?

Comment: @JackFleeting I'm sorry for the lack of code, I posted this when I was at work. url = "url"

url_response = requests.get(url)
url_content = BeautifulSoup(url_response.content, 'html5lib')

code = url_content.find('div', 'article_details').get_text()

print(code) Seems like RegEx is going to do the job, I'm going to try that now. Thanks!

Comment: @JimmySmith I think regex is going to the job, here's a snippet of the code. I'm not sure how to format it correctly, hope this will work because it didn't on the previous comment, sorry! 'code' url = "url"

url_response = requests.get(url)
url_content = BeautifulSoup(url_response.content, 'html5lib')

code = url_content.find('div', 'article_details').get_text()

print(code) 'code' Target variable """!012WR55wr"!.""" Desired output: 55

Comment: Can you show the output of `print(code)`?

Comment: @JackFleeting The output of code is """ !012WR55wr"! """. Once I see the output, I can tell that 55 is the number that I would like to store and use for calculations. In the future, if I scrape the same website, number 55 can change to a different value, but it will remain in the same position. So far RegEX is doing the job, however I ran into a problem where RegEX returns a list of integers, now I'm trying to figure out how I can extract these integers from a list so that I can perform calculations on these integers.

Comment: @JackFleeting I was being stupid... I solved my problem now. I'm going to update the original post with my solution. Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is RegEX - regular expression. you can import re in python and start using its functions like search and findall, I can explain you the process by an example.

```
import re

sample_str = '''!012WR55wr"!.'''

extracted_integers =  re.findall(r"\d+" , sample_str) # extracting string with patterns like digits.
extracted_integers = [int(i) for i in extracted_integers] # converting string to integer
print(extracted_integers) # you can see all your integers from your string.
```

if you want to learn more about regEx you can see this awsome blog - https://medium.com/factory-mind/regex-tutorial-a-simple-cheatsheet-by-examples-649dc1c3f285

if you to check regex with some test cases you can use this online tool - https://regex101.com/

Comment: Thank you, sorry for the late reply. Regex seems to work really nicely for this, however it returns a list of integers. My problem now is that I would like to perform calculations on that integer. Is there a way to extract that integer from a list and store it in a separate variable?

Comment: I was being stupid... I solved my problem now. I'm going to update the original post with my solution. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Glad to here that please mark my answer as a accepted one, if this solved your problem completely